# Defaulting Lead.company

Tags: account, leads

Can we set a default value of the company field of Lead to logged in User's company field so that at the time of conversion, Account name becomes User's company name.  I tried Workflow with Field update but it didn't worked. Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.

[image: Please find the attached image for Workflow and Field Update Action]

```
   32.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION‌​,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO 
03:14:27.097 (97629552)|EXECUTION_STARTED 
03:14:27.097 (97659820)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Lead 
03:14:27.098 (98261386)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Lead 
03:14:27.098 (98273470)|EXECUTION_FINISHED –
```

Comment: Do you have an account for each of the companies on the user record?

Comment: you should post your workflow; also note that for workflows to execute during Lead Conversion, you need to check the box under `Customize | Lead | Settings | Require Validation For Converted Leads`

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks for your response. I have added the image for Workflow and Field update action. The 'Require Validation For Converted Leads' has already been checked for Leads. Kindly suggest

Comment: your field update formula got cropped out - please revise posted image.  Also, to debug this issue, turn debug logs on just before you do the Lead Convert - then examine the workflow portion of the log to see the order of execution

Comment: @crop1645- I have posted the image with formula editor. I did debug and at the time of saving a Lead below is the log:                                                                                        32.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
03:14:27.097 (97629552)|EXECUTION_STARTED
03:14:27.097 (97659820)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Lead
03:14:27.098 (98261386)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Lead
03:14:27.098 (98273470)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations

1. `Lead.company` is a required field so no new Lead can be saved without one
2. The workflow will only execute when the `Lead.company` is changed (from either null to a value, or a valueX to valueY). The workflow will not execute when the running user is different if the `Lead.company` has not changed
3. Normally, if you want to default a field value using the point-and-click interface, you use the Default Value portion of the field definition. However, for standard fields, this is not an available option

So, how to default the Lead.company name

The answer depends on how the Lead is created.

1. If created from a marketing automation system or web-to-lead, the running user will most likely be some 'api-type' user and hence not useful to you as a default
2. If created from the standard page layout for Lead - you'll need to remove the required field on Lead.company and change the workflow rule to execute when lead.company = null (on Create) and set to running user.company (why your users have different companies, I'm unclear)
3. You can also default the Lead.company by overriding the New button with the following VF page that defaults the standard Edit page company field (id=lea3 per Firebug)

   ```
   <apex:page standardController="Lead" 
     action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.New,$ObjectType.Lead,[lea3=$User.companyname],true)}">
   </apex:page>
   ```