# Defaulting Account name

Tags: account, contact

Can we default Account field's name in Contact object? My requirement is I want to set the Account's value (in Contact) to the logged in user's Company name. I tried this code but it didn't worked. gave an error: Field $Action.accountId.New does not exist. Check spelling

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" 
   action="{!URLFOR($Action.accountId.New,$ObjectType.accountId,[con3=$User.companyname],true)}">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: So are you talking about contacts created by external users? Portal or Community users creating those contacts?

Comment: Contacts being created by internal users.

Comment: I think you are slightly confused. A single internal user can own multiple account records. The field on Account (and every object) is OwnerId. A partner or community user is a different story as they belong to a single Account via a Contract / User record. So do you have some custom business process in place that maintains a 1 to 1 relationship between Users and Accounts?

Comment: Im actually referring to Users object. Lets say I have created 2 users (User1 and User2) in my Salesforce org both with same Company name (ABC Ltd). Now no matter which user logs in, the new Contact should always have a default Account name as ABC Ltd.

Comment: Salesforce Learner -- I answered this same question for you on Leads here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/55033/2602; the approach will be similar except you need to default accountId, not a string -- your User object will need a lookup field to Account

Comment: Thanks... I did tried your suggestion earlier, by changing the "New" button on Contact with a VF page. but it didn't solved the problem. It gave an error "Field $Action.accountId.New does not exist. Check spelling". I'm adding the code with the question.

Comment: Just an FYI... I have added record types to Contact to display different page layouts at the time of creation. Hope it gets uninfected with that.