# Prepopulating company name in Lead object

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, workflow

I want to prepopulate the `Company` field in the `Lead object`.

The idea here is that I don't want a `Company Name` in my `Leads` ie the `Account object` is not necessary for me.
Now, as you know the company name is a **standard required field** so it cannot be removed and it cannot be renamed, so, I want it to be automatically populate it to say, XYZ.

To achieve this, I have tried using workflow but the user will have to write some gibberish for the record to save and then modify it. The same goes for `flow`.

I have also tried using `before trigger` but the `validation` runs before the `trigger`, so it gives an error if the company field is left blank.

I have also tried using redirecting the `New Lead button` to a `custom VF page` and that does seem to work but only on Salesforce classic. See [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54596/defaulting-lead-company)

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" 
  action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.New,$ObjectType.Lead,[lea3=$User.companyname],true)}">
</apex:page>
```

I don't have enough knowledge of LWC but I think that this might be achievable using the same if I redirect the `New Lead button` to the component. Can you guys help me with that?

Or is there any other way I can go about it? Maybe using the `URL parameters`. Any help is welcome. :)

Comment: Consider upvoting this [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdW6bUAF/default-values-on-standard-fields) which requests for this feature.

Comment: Quick Action is the easiest and out of the box way to solve this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.predefined_field_values.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

If you [Enable Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_enable.htm&type=5), the Company field is no longer required, and you can even remove it from the page entirely. Note that there are some [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_behavior.htm&type=5) to be aware of, so try this in a Sandbox first.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Triggers & Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), if the record is being created from standard UI, then the required field defined at page layout or field definition are evaluated first. So, before trigger (apex or flow based) won't help you out.

You can create a LWC using [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form) [Note that the sample codes are provided in the same page]. Also, you cannot use `lightning-record-form` because it doesn't support pre-populating the fields. After you have created this LWC, you can override the New button to use this LWC from the object settings page (see screenshot below) . Under `Lightning Experience Override`, you would be able to see the LWC name in the drop down.

[image]